Blender UV Mapping - FBX models in arch viz
Relative newbie and I'm here having slogged through this issue for last 2 days.
I'm trying to come up with a workflow to automatically map (or at least semi-automate) FBX models from BIM programs and I'm getting a bit stuck.
I need to map a texture around the wall so it tiles continuously. I've tried unwrap, Smart Project unwrap and follow active quads all with marking and unmarking seams, but not seem to work.
Thanks


@Duarte Farrajota Ramos, The answers from the link that you used to close this question does not create a continuos seamless texture that wraps around the model. https://gyazo.com/3a74ff3880fc74c7966d4fc4b361c3e3  To achieve this it is necessary to UV unwrap in such a way that the walls unwrap in a single horizontal strip extending from U=0 to U=1 in the UV space then from U=0, Y=0 scale up as required using a whole number.  https://gyazo.com/3e564d39aba9df691b857cc53717d1a3

Not sure if the OP expects a continuous seamless texture, I'd expect real buildings to have some sort of discontinuity at most corners above a certain threshold. Maybe Chris Ford can clarify if the duplicate satisfies his needs or not

Quote from the question "I need to map a texture around the wall so it tiles continuously"

Thanks veru much @fingeredfrog - I have recreated the solution here and nearly got it to work. Can I ask, did you unrwap the wall normally or apply a cube or smart unwrap. I have the shader node setup as you have but the uvediting view isnt landscape like yours, is still stacked.

Unfortunately I don't have time this evening to give a full answer but will do tomorrow. Setting out the Uv's is not difficult at all IF you have a mesh with the correct geometry. From the image you posted yours is not ideal. While the model itself is a single mesh object all the walls appear to be made up of separate meshes. This means the model needs to be edited so that hidden faces are deleted and unconnected vertices of one wall section need to be merged to the appropriate vertices of the next section.

When this is done then UV unwrapping for example the outer wall, is just a matter of assigning one vertical edge of the outer walls a UV seam  and then isolating it from the rest of the model using seams along the horizontal edges.(top and bottom as required). This outer wall will then unwrap as a single long UV island which is scaled up to suit your seamless tileable texture. The result is the tileable texture will be repeated along the walls length without any visible seams. Example file   https://blend-exchange.com/b/rDrzY9oa

Hey @3fingeredfrog - before you get to this, I think I have found a way to do it based on your prompt above. Ive selected all external wall faces and used UV packmaster to unwrap and align in a row. I think thats worked for me so your advice above was spot on.
It will be slightly manual each time I import an FBX architectural model but its not a huge time suck as I will only need to do this for walls with visible texture joins.
Thankyou!

If it works for you then all is good. :)  And thanks for letting me know.

Standard workflow with marking seams and unwrapping is the way to go here. I would recommend trying again until you find a way to make it work. Watching some tutorials could be a good idea. Looking into various selection tools might also be a good idea. For example you can select linked flat faces on top and bottom

, or select coplanar( Shift  +  G  menu) then select boundary edge loop to select a lot of edges

that might be useful to select all at once in this case. Other loop selection tools are also helpful as well as selecting shortest path( Ctrl  + click on another element after selecting something). Mastering or getting used to selection functionality can speedup the process and make it a lot easier and faster. It's the best approach because it's more flexible than any automatic ways to map textures as you may want to map different kinds textures in different ways and this standard approach is really the most robust and flexible approach there is.
Keep in mind you can set hotkeys and add operators to your Quick Favourites menu( Q ). Just right click on something in the menus to do so:

Select Linked Flat faces used to be  Ctrl  +  Shift  +  Alt  +  F   by default quite a few versions ago and it may be useful to have it if you do that a lot.
In any case, just wanted to let you know it's definitely possible to make this workflow work for you with practice and it can become very flexible, fast, easy and intuitive workflow even when it's done manually.

Thanks @Martynas, thats really helpful. Appreciate you taking the time to answer. I'll have a play and test it out.
